# Android: Service stops and restarts after Activity crash

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have an `Activity` that launches a `Service` with `startService` and then `binds` to that Service for communication between the two. In the `onStart` of the service i return `START_STICKY` because I want the Service to keep running no matter what. 
My Service contains the logic and the Activity is responsible for the UI.

The problem is: if I close the app (swiping it away from the recent apps) the service keeps running without any problem. But if the activity crashes (for an unhandled exception) the service stops working without even calling the `onDestroy` and then restarts from the `onCreate` and `onStart`.

How can I keep the Service running even if the app crashes?

EDIT: if the system reaches low memory the app is force-closed and the service stops and restarts. So the problem is not only on crashes therefor the solution can't be to put all the codes in try-catch blocks.

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing you can't. Try to handle the exceptions. Use `Try-catch`

Answer (score 1):

you should use a remote service in a different process adding

```
android:process=":whatever"
```

And binding it with [ServiceConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html#onServiceDisconnected%28android.content.ComponentName%29).